# Is cost management part of Project Management?

Tags: cost-management

Is Cost Management (Estimation and Control) part of Project Mangement? 
Are cost management techniques (COCOMO, Function Point, etc) part of PM? Or only Software Project Management?

I ask this because whenever I open a book about Project Management, I don't find these topics covered.

Answer (score 1):

Unequivocal yes.  I do not think I've ever picked up a PM book without a cost management topic.

Comment: I have here in my desk PM books that sadly don't cover these techniques. In fact I have only one that does and it is in japanese. And sadly it seems I can not ask for recommendations in the site :(

Comment: Yeah, recommendations for SW tools and PM books, like those written by Harold Kerzner, PhD., are off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. it is definitely a core part of project management. in fact, it is part of the project management triangle. different industries, and different organisations would have different preferred method to manage cost. however, it is also noted that there are different sizes of projects, and some PM do not really need to manage cost a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Cost is part of the triple constraint: schedule, budget (cost), and scope. The triple constraint is as fundamental as you can get in project management, regardless of the specific industry. So even if you don't see a section explicitly labeled "Cost Management" in a textbook, it is something you need to know about for any aspect of the project that requires spending money: procurement, hiring and paying resources, travel, etc.